# How to display the calculations from a filter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I wrote an app to convert between decimal values and negabinary.

http://dev.golightlyplus.com/playground/negabinary/

I wrote a custom filter so I could do

```
{{decimal | negabinary}}
```

The code for it being..

```
var negabinaryApp = angular.module('negabinaryApp', []);

negabinaryApp.filter('negabinary', function() {

    return function (decimal) {

        if (isNaN(decimal)) return "not a number";

        var negabinary = [];
        var base = -2;
        var remainder;

        while(decimal != 0) {

            remainder = decimal % base;
            decimal = Math.ceil(decimal / base);
            negabinary.push(remainder >= 0 ? remainder : -remainder);
        }

        return negabinary.reverse().join('');
    }
});
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to also show the calculations on the page.

I could create an array of the calculations for each cycle through the while loop. But how do I then bind them to the HTML? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual functionality of your particular filter is distracting from the purpose of the question. To simplify, your question is: "how can I display that output of a filter that takes a string, and parses it into HTML"?

This would apply equally to your case as it would to a case where you just wrap the text in `<pre>`, for example.

The key, is to bind the output to `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div ng-bind-html="decimal | negabinary">
```

Here's a simple (and useless) example:

```
.filter("strongify", function(){
  return function(str){
    return "<strong>" + str + "</strong>";
  }
});
```

which can be used similarly:

```
<div ng-bind-html="name | strongify">
```

Here's a plunker that breaks the text into paragraphs of `<p>`: http://plnkr.co/edit/RN5TqwNRRjMjynwInNyn?p=preview

Note, that you will also need to add `ngSanitize` dependency or otherwise do `$sce.trustAsHtml` on the output.